# Graph Theory Describing a Tree

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that a tree has 1000 vertices of degree eight and 40 vertices of degree 5 and perhaps other vertices.  Can such a tree have fewer than 4000 leaves?  If yes how can I describe one such tree,else  how to argue that such tree cannot exist ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

No. If n is the total number of vertices, then the tree has n-1 edges, and the sum of the vertex degrees is twice the number of edges, so 2n-2.

Let r be the number of nodes of degree 8, s the nodes of degree 1 (the leaves) and t the remaining ones (so they have degree at least 2). Then n=r+s+t and 2n-2=2r+2s+2t-2 >= 8r+s+2t (lower bound for the sum of the degrees). So s-2>= 6r. For r=1000 you have over 6000 leaves.